# Image showing in Android Studio but not on phone

Tags: android, listview, imageview

As you can see below this is what Android Studio shows:

[image]

However, when I run this app on my phone the List View shows with just a blank image (i.e - a space) above it where the "somewhere over the rainbow" should be.

The List View is working fine. It consists of one image view and 2 text views. (This image view is working if it helps). If any of this is possibly interfering then I will post the code here, but I find that hard to believe.

The one thing that I was unsure of was whether I could use relative view when defining the cells for the list view in the separate xml file. I don't see why not but it's the only thing that I could think of.

Basically Android studio shows everything working but on the phone/emulator it is not the case. Hence, I am finding it very hard to locate the problem.

I'm new to the Android development scene so go easy on me.

**EDIT**

The image is .png format and is located in the drawable folder. I also have another .png image in the drawable folder that seems to give no problems. Why is this the case? The original image is clearly not corrupt as it shows up in Android Studio

**SOLUTION**

Had to move image to "mipmap-xxhdpi" folder due to size

Comment: See my answer, provide more info if this is not the solution.

Comment: Image should be displayed irrespective of your drawable folders. There may be some other issue . Please provide more info or post your code.

Comment: Not very helpful, please provide the XML layout

Comment: "Image should be displayed irrespective of your drawable folders" this appears to be simply not true.  I tested it extensively and it simply won't display it (on a Note, say) if it is "way out of size" or if it is in "drawable" and it is very large.  Using **"drawable-nodpi"** seems to make it work like on normal operating systems - it actually draws it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found same problem today . So first check height and width of image and based on it put image into different drawable folder. i.e If image size is 1280 x 840 than put image in drawable-xxhdpi folder.

Comment: There is only one 'drawable' folder. But yes, the image size is massive, this is clearly the issue.

Comment: Solved, had to move to 'mipmap - xxhdpi' folder

Comment: I will rate you best answer for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: If your image is too large than use universal image loader or volley for fast image loading

Answer (score 28):

I stumbled across the same issue and found the answer below:
(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40397892/7614252)

What I did to make it work is to change the automatic key assigned (populated via Drag/Drop ImageView) from `app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"` to `android:src="@drawable/logo"` in Text tab to make it appear on both the emulator and the device e.g

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5" />
```

Comment: Thank you @SamyMassoud .

Comment: @SamyMassoud No, it shouldn't. Just because it happened to be the solution for you does not mean it was the solution for the OP.

Comment: Somehow, I ended with tools:srcCompat instead of either of the above two- changing it to app:srcCompat worked for me, so I suppose the takeaway here is to be aware that there's a few different options, and whatever Android Studio supplied you with might not work.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this same question, can you check which folder it is in. For me the problem was putting it inside the drawable folder, whilst it should be drawable-nodpi

Also state what device you're seeing this problem, is this multiple devices?

[Image not appearing on HTC One M8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703442/image-not-appearing-on-htc-one-m8)

Here are relevant answers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The image is indeed in the "drawable" folder. It is png format. I also have another image in the "drawable" folder, also png format. However, this one seems to work. So the problem must be the image. But how does this make sense?

Comment: I had the same thing, only one image was not working. Could you try renaming the folder to drawable-nodpi. I must say I really don't know why it worked but it did.

Comment: I will have to change all references to the folder too then, will I still proceed?

Comment: just select the folder, do Shift F6, android studio will fix the references for you, it might actually even do it without refactor. (Always use Shift F6 when you rename classes or variables for that matter ;))

Comment: **drawable-nodpi** seems to work well ... thanks so much @MathijsSegers

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that putting bigger images into a higher HDPI folder works on the Samsung Galaxy S4 when viewing images.

The problem I had was that the drawable folder for the higher HDPI did not exist.
But if you create a new folder and name it `drawable-xxhdpi` or 
`drawable-(whateverxxxhdpi)`, place it in `[path to your project folder]\app\src\main\res\`, then place your image there, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

if you use `android:src` or `app:srcCompat` use `android:background` instead:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_image"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. my image was displayed on the image but was not showing on my android device...

I changed

```
tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wifi"
```

and replaced it with

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wifi"
```

Answer (score 1):

An earlier duplicate question was asked (I don't have enough points to flag the question above as a duplicate) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474761/android-drawable-not-showing-up) and Lukap's suggestion of putting the drawable into a drawable-hdpi folder worked for me.  [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729388/drawable-folders?noredirect=1&lq=1) the use of three drawable folders (-hdpi, -mdpi, -ldpi) used to be standard practice.

While putting the image into any of the mipmap folders also worked for me (and then of course changing `android:src="@drawable/image"` to `android:src="@mipmap/image"`), the Android Developer page for [App Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) says that mipmap resources are for "Drawable files for different launcher icon densities".  So putting images other than launch icons in a mipmap folder seems to work but does not follow Android convention.

It seems to me like a bug for the image to not display when in the only available drawable/ folder since others recommend using the drawable folder for all images that are not app icons.  On the Android Developer page for Providing Resources, there is a section that discusses the approach Android uses for [selecting the best matching resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) using an example where several drawable resources are available.

> To demonstrate how Android selects an alternative resource, assume the
>   following drawable directories each contain different versions of the
>   same images:
>
> drawable/
>     drawable-en/
>     drawable-fr-rCA/
>     drawable-en-port/
>     drawable-en-notouch-12key/
>     drawable-port-ldpi/
>     drawable-port-notouch-12key/
>
> And assume the following is the device
>   configuration:
>
> Locale = en-GB
>     Screen orientation = port
>     Screen pixel density = hdpi
>     Touchscreen type = notouch
>     Primary text input method = 12key
>
> By comparing the device configuration to the available alternative
>   resources, Android selects drawables from drawable-en-port.

If there is only one drawable/ folder, you would think the android "logic" would select the only available drawable resource.

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issue but this what i added to my manifest file
`<application
        //this solve it for me.
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        // Add this if the previuos line didn't solve the problem
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and I solved it by adding this in my imageView xml code

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```